# Display latest email filtering on subject and sendername

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I created Excel VBA code that opens email from Outlook based on sender name and subject. I search Inbox, Sent Items and Mail 2023 archive.

When I have multiple emails with that subject, it shows the oldest mail not the most recent. Tried `find`, `findnext`, `getlast`, `sort`.

```vb
Sub display_email()
    
    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim fol1 As Outlook.Folder
    Dim fol2 As Outlook.Folder
    Dim fol3 As Outlook.Folder
    
    Dim rootfol As Outlook.Folder
    Dim item As Object
    Dim FilterText As String
    Dim SubjectText As String
            
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set rootfol = ns.Folders(1)
    Set fol1 = rootfol.Folders("Inbox")
    Set fol2 = rootfol.Folders("Sent Items")
    Set fol3 = rootfol.Folders("Archive").Folders("Mail 2023")

    SubjectText = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    
    If Mid(SubjectText, 3, 1) = ":" Or Mid(SubjectText, 4, 1) = ":" Then
        SubjectText = Mid(SubjectText, 5)
    End If
    
    FilterText = "[SenderName] = '" & ActiveCell.Value & "'"
    FilterText = FilterText & "AND [Subject] = '" & SubjectText & "'"

    Set item = fol1.Items.Find(FilterText)
    If item Is Nothing Then
        Set item = fol2.Items.Find(FilterText)
    End If
    If item Is Nothing Then
        Set item = fol3.Items.Find(FilterText)
    End If
    
    If item Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing was Found", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set msg = item
    msg.Display True
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Items.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort) method which sorts the collection of items by the specified property. The index for the collection is reset to 1 upon completion of this method.

So, before calling the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods you need to sort the collection to get the most recent ones first.

```
Dim nItems as Outlook.Items 
Set nItems = fol1.Items 
nItems.Sort "ReceivedTime"
Set item = nItems.Find(FilterText)
```

Also if you need to search for items in multiple folders you may consider using the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class instead. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

Read more about that method in the article that I wrote for the technical blog, see [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/).